# $\int_{0}^{3} \int_{x^2}^{9} x^3e^{y^2}dydx$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the following integral 
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{3} \int_{x^2}^{9} x^3e^{y^2}dydx
\end{equation}

I am trying to solve this integral ,can someone give any hint to do this .

Comment: Switch the order:  $\int e^{y^2} \ dy$ has no closed form, so a bad idea to keep it as is.

Comment: @muhammad mohsin if u know double integration then it is very simple to do.

Comment: @Randall, switching the order doesn't help.

Comment: Is the problem written correctly?  But as it is the integral cannot be done.

Comment: Hmmm....  I don't see any exploitable symmetry either.

Comment: Like @Paul, I'd like to know if the problem is asked correctly.

Answer (score 4):

When you switch the order of integration you get
$$\int_{0}^{9} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}} x^3e^{y^2}dxdy$$
which is easy to evaluate for the first integral.  However, after the first integral is done, you are left with
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^9 y^2e^{y^2}dy$$
which has no closed form.  So there is no way to get an answer here.